# Do gaming consoles come with built-in crash reporting system for the developers?

Tags: console, exceptions, crash

I'm working at a game industry and my company's planning on releasing some games for consoles (PS, Nintendo Switch).

I'm wondering if we should integrate some kind of custom crash reporting system into the games to observe the crashes our users are experiencing, or if Sony (and Nintendo) provides a way for the developers to access the crashes without having to set up a crash reporting system ourselves.

Comment: Although I wish you find an answer to your question, please note that this information could be protected by NDAs, and so it might not be publicly shareable by those who know.

Comment: As a registered PlayStation and Nintendo developer, your company should have access to the official documentation for these platforms and the services they offer. Those will generally be more reliable ways to find out the latest and greatest official information. If you're unable to find this information in the provided docs, platforms like this often host developer Q&A boards or other feedback channels (safely behind their NDA curtain, unlike here), or have representatives you can contact for support and clarification. I'd recommend focusing on those angles.